# Django Online File Browser

Tags: django

everyone：

Recently,I meet a problem when I'm using Django to devlope my site.
    In my project, one requirement is to view file online.

That is to say, one can browses files of formats:pdf, jpeg,doc and so on
    directly in browsers such as chrome or firefox and so on.

I know this can be done by flash,FlexPaper is one solution. But in django, 
   not in flash,is there any other solutions? Anyone knows that? If not, I can 
   only use flexpaper and maybe site can't be accessed via apple devices

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use https://github.com/NetAngels/django-webodt ([documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/django-webodt/)) with option inline=True:

```
render_to_response(..., inline=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of non-flash file browser plugins out there: Elfinder has a [Django connector](https://github.com/mikery/django-elfinder), and you can probably get an integration with [CKfinder](http://cksource.com/ckfinder).

The django packages page also has a list of django file browsers [link](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/file-managers/).